# Complexity estimation for simple recursive algorithm

Tags: scala, time-complexity

I wrote a code on `Scala`. And now I want to estimate time and memory complexity.

**Problem statement**

Given a positive integer `n`, find the least number of perfect square numbers (for example, 1, 4, 9, 16, ...) which sum to `n`.

For example, given `n = 12`, return `3` because `12 = 4 + 4 + 4`; given `n = 13`, return `2` because `13 = 4 + 9`.

**My code**

```
def numSquares(n: Int): Int = {
  import java.lang.Math._

  def traverse(n: Int, ns: Int): Int = {
    val max = ((num: Int) => {
      val sq = sqrt(num)
      // a perfect square!
      if (sq == floor(sq))
        num.toInt
      else
        sq.toInt * sq.toInt
    })(n)

    if (n == max)
      ns + 1
    else
      traverse(n - max, ns + 1)
  }

  traverse(n, 0)
}
```

I use here a recursion solution. So IMHO time complexity is `O(n)`, because  I need to traverse over the sequence of numbers using recursion. Am I right? Have I missed anything?

Comment: Maybe more importantly, you might want to fix the code, since it's incorrect. `numSquares(12)` gives `4`

Comment: It's not O(N). You don't recurse N times, since n - max is a lot smaller than n. I can't prove it right now, but  my guess is it's O(log(n))

Comment: Oh, I'm being dense. It's O(1), because the answer is always 4 or less, and you don't iterate over alternative ways of summing squares. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem

Comment: Oh, yes. I've already read it. But I do not know how to apply it to my case.

Comment: It says that, if your algorithm is correct, it will never produce an answer more than 4. So it cannot recurse more than 3 times (as the terminating case is at least 1). This is a fixed number, independent of N.  So, O(1). HOWEVER, your algorithm assumes the the minimal number of squares always includes the largest square smaller than N.  This isn't true (12 = 9 + 1+ 1 +1, according to your algorithm, but 4+4+4 is shorter). That means you need to try more combinations of squares that add up to N, and that probably means it cannot be O(1).